# Increasing MySQL Performance - InnoDB

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, innodb, my.cnf

I am working with a Linux **CentOS** and with **MySQL**, until now, this is the content of **my.cnf**:

```
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
max_connections = 750
max_connect_errors = 750
connect_timeout = 28800
max_allowed_packet = 500M
character_set_server = utf8
query_cache_size = 500M
```

I am trying to increase MySQL performance with that parameters, I was reading some of them are deprecated, so, I chose InnoDB as engine and tried to setting it as follow:

```
default_storage_engine = INNODB
innodb_buffer_pool_size=9G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=64
```

So the the final setting of my.cnf is:

```
sql_mode="NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER"
max_connections = 750
max_connect_errors = 750
connect_timeout = 28800
character_set_server = utf8
default_storage_engine = INNODB
innodb_buffer_pool_size=6G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=64
```

But at the end, server get overloaded without using all available memory (*3GB/8GB and not 6GB/8GB* how I expected of using *innodb_buffer_pool_size*) and I must restart MySQL service to restore and normalize service status.

How can I really improve MySQL performance? or which recommendations can you give me?

In advance, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2`.Additional info can be found here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer, today I will test it. Hope it works!

Comment: Hi. It's not easy to help you without additional information on your setup. You may edit your original question to provide it. It particular it is not clear what your server is doing. You may profile your server using a tools like `mytop`, http://poormansprofiler.org/ and `perf top -p` and `strace` while you use linux.

Comment: Next month I have a new pression test, please wait until then so I will tell you

Answer (score 1):

`query_cache_size = 500M` kills performance.

*Every* write to a table purges *all* entries in the QC for that table.  And it does that task in a way that is very slow for a very large QC.

50M is a practical max for that setting.

And the QC is taking memory away from InnoDB's buffer_pool, where it may be more useful.

If you have no other applications on the machine and you lower the QC, then 6G for the buffer_pool on an 8GB machine should be ok.  Keep an eye on swapping -- such is terrible for performance.

Also, only 6 for `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` -- 1G per instance is the recommendation.

`connect_timeout` relates to giving up on a making a connection, not on how long the connection can stay around.  `60` or less is reasonable.

But...  Typically poor performance comes from poor indexes (especially lack of 'composite' indexes when needed) and hiding indexed columns inside function calls (eg, `WHERE DATE(created_at) = '...'`).

So, let's see what queries are slow.

Comment: I did not understand something: 1G for innodb_buffer_pool_instances or what?
I am sure that the problem are not the indexes.
The problem is that suddenly max_used_connections and threads_connected get same values (e.g. max_used_connections - 150 and threads_connected - 150), so, mysql service starts to work slow and when I checked memory use, there are 5 GB free, so I do not understand why mysql service get crashed when there is a lot of memory RAM free to use...

Comment: I must remove query_cache_size since I am using innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Comment: MySQL stumbles over itself when you have more than a few dozen queries running at once.  The usual fix is to speed up the queries so that that does not happen.  A huge QC slows things down.  Poor indexes slows things.  Etc.  Let's see some of the 150 queries running at once.  Provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` also.

Comment: And...  For a 3GB buffer_pool, set buffer_pool_instances to only 3.  For 6GB, only 6 instances.  You say "crash"; perhaps it was "so slow that it felt like a crash"?  That would be consistent with poor indexes.

Comment: And... Using query cache is optional, _but_ its size should not be more than 50M.  You _must_ use buffer_pool.

Comment: As I tell you, indexes are not the problem. Do not be a closed mind, if that limit is standard and real, I can not image how many web sites can survive with that limit when they process a million of queries by second. Next month I have a new pression test, please wait until then so I will tell you if a new configuration that I found and I set works or not.

Comment: I anxiously away your experimentation.  The 50M is empirically derived from years of experience; it is not a 'hard' number.  Only a small fraction of a 'typical' web site's queries are _exactly_ the same, so, only a fraction of queries can effectively be cached _in the Query Cache_.  _All_ data is cached in the buffer_pool.  So, it tends to be better use of RAM to give more to the buffer_pool and less to the QC.  Again, this is from years of experience; YMMV (Your Mileage May Vary).

Comment: And...  13 years of my career were with a large web site.  After some experimenting, it was determined that all but 2 of about 100 MySQL servers should turn the QC completely off.  Keep in mind that when _any_ write occurs, _all_ entries in the QC for that table are purged.  This is more costly for bigger QC size.